# Arduino Serial Communication from Third Party Platform

Tags: c++, boost, arduino, boost-asio

I'm designing a Serial Communications platform that sends data from c++ code that uses Boost.Asio, and receives it via Arduino.

My test program structure is just an echoing program: the computer sends some characters over to the Arduino, the Arduino sends the characters back to the computer, which `async_read`s them.

I'm close to having good communication asynchronously, but one problem persists. Disclosure: my Baud rates are matching, at least in the two programs. My problem is that whenever I send data at a baud rate other than 9600, some sort of error occurs between echoing the data from the Arduino to the computer. An unknown character is appended to the start of the message, and in some cases, two unknown characters are appended.

It would seem that this could be some form of synchronization issue with the start and stop bits, but I'm not sure. Can anyone suggest anything I should check (besides that my baud rates, which are indeed matching)? I'm not sure where I should look for the problem.

***Echo program on computer side:***

```
#ifndef IOSTREAM_H
#include <iostream>
#endif
#ifndef SERIAL_H
#include "serial.h"
#endif
#include <time.h>
#define PORT "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411"

int main(){
    std::clock_t t;
    t = std::clock();
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    Serial::Serial serial(PORT, &io, 19200);
    if(!serial.is_open()){
      serial.open(PORT);
    }
    std::string s = "hellomynameiswill~";
    serial.async_write(s);
    serial.async_read_until("\n");
    io.run();
    t = std::clock() - t;
    std::cout << "Execution time:" << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}
```

***Echo program on Arduino side:***

```
boolean isSerial = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  isSerial = false;
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
//    delay(1);
    char byteRead = Serial.read();
    isSerial = true;
    while(byteRead != 126){
      if(Serial.available() > 0){      
        Serial.print(byteRead);
        byteRead = Serial.read();
      }
    }
    if(isSerial){
      Serial.print('\n');
    }
  } 
}
```

The output I receive on the echo program with a baud rate other than 9600 is always either `"?hellomynameiswill~"` or `"??hellomynameiswill~"`. The latter output is much more common. I am using an Arduino Uno.

Edit 2: The ? at the beginning of the sequence is a negative integer when converted to ascii value.  I'm still not sure how to approach the fix.
Edit 3: The ? at the beginning of the sequence can be traced to the original boost::asio::async_write of the message to the arduino.  Alternating between boost::asio::async_write and boost::asio::write makes no difference as to the outputted text.

Comment: Hello, and welcome on stackoverflow: can you post your data logs, and show what those characters are? Can you also show your code (if it's only an echo, both codes should be fairly simple). Also could you tell what "Arduino" are you using?

Comment: I'm using an arduino uno

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it turns out that a certain assortment of characters are sent across the serial stream when it is first opened by the program, which was happening on every read for me because the program only read from the echoing arduino once per program execution.  I fixed the ?'s at the beginning, which were of a negative value by just selectively taking out the negative values waiting in the UART buffer. Since ascii values range from 0 to 127, so they are technically signed, and that, I believe, is why I was even able to get negative character values.  I cleaned the UART buffer by adding a while loop that looked for negative character values, and if the value of the incoming char was negative, the program removed the char from the buffer.  Here is the updated code on the arduino side, which is where the problems were:

```
#include <StackArray.h>

boolean isSerial = false;
int num = 0;
StackArray<char> serialOut;
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void cleanSerial(){
  char junk = Serial.peek();
  while(int(junk) < 0 || int(junk) > 127){
    Serial.read();
    junk = Serial.peek();
  }
}

void loop() {
  isSerial = false;
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
    cleanSerial();
    char byteRead = 0;
    isSerial = true;
    while(byteRead != 126){
      if(Serial.available() > 0){      
        byteRead = Serial.read();
        serialOut.push(byteRead);   
     }
    }
  } 
  if(isSerial){
     writeFromStack();
  }
  num++;
}
void blink(int times, int duration){
  for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(duration);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(duration);
  }
}
void writeFromStack(){
  int arrayLen = serialOut.count();
  char tempBuf[arrayLen];
  for(int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++){
    tempBuf[arrayLen - 1 - i] = serialOut.pop();
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++){
    Serial.print(tempBuf[i]);
  }
  Serial.print('\n');
}
```

Thank you all. Keep calm and code on.